# WPF howto click out of rows in DataGrid to unselect item

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

How can I remove selection of Row if I click outside of rows. Like in the red area of the image showing below

[image]

The related xaml shows below:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid x:Name="ClientsList" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ClientItems}" LostFocus="ClientsList_LostFocus" Background="Green">
        </DataGrid>

        <StackPanel Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="AddButton"  Margin="2,0,0,0" Content="+" Height="25" Width="40" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Margin="2,0,0,0" Content="-" Height="25" Width="40" Click="DeleteButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In you case if empty area was clicked then `OriginalSource` is gonna be `ScrollViewer` (if no additional styling applied). Try to add the following `MouseUp` event handler to `DataGrid`:

```
    private void OnDataGridMouseUp(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is ScrollViewer)
        {
            ((DataGrid) o).UnselectAll();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) to identify when you lose focus of the `DataGrid`, and cancel selection of selected rows in that event.

For cancel selection:

```
yourDataGrid.UnselectAll()
```

Comment: It is not working. The red area is one part of DataGrid. I click here, it don't fire `LostFocus` event

Comment: What is this area? Kindly show me the related `xaml` code

Comment: So this is the empty grid area (in red square)?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question. I add the green background for DataGrid, This image shows more clearly